# Character Array Not Getting Value Correctly

Tags: javascript

This is a very specific question to software I am developing. I created and am using a text encoder however a small bug exists in the code.

Demo: https://dotjersh.github.io/sangwa/

If I input `70` one of the values it can return is `F0`.
When I decode `F0` however, the result is `7)`. 
I have tested the code with tons of data and different situations and it works with every other scenario other then this one.

Code:

```
var sangwa = {
  array: "~!1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8(9)0_-=+  qQwWeErRtTyYuUiIoOpP[{]}\\|aAsSdDfFgGhHjJkKlL;:\"'zZxXcCvVbBnNmM,<.>/?",
  key: function(value){
    var a = this.array + this.array;
    if(typeof value === "string"){
      return this.array.indexOf(value);
    } else if(typeof value === "number"){
      if(value >= 0){
        return a[value];
      } else {
        return a[this.array.length + value];
      }
    } else {
      return this.array + this.array;
    }
  }
}

sangwa.encode = function(value){
  var result = "";

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2;

  value = "A" + value;

  for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
    result += sangwa.key(sangwa.key(value[i]) + rand);
  }

  return result;
}

sangwa.decode = function(value){
  var result = "";

  var rand = parseInt(sangwa.key(value[0]) - sangwa.key("A"));

  for(var i = 1; i < value.length; i++){
    result += sangwa.key(sangwa.key(value[i]) - rand);
  }

  return result;
}
```

The code is on github if you want to suggest a change that way:
https://github.com/dotjersh/sangwa/blob/master/sangwa.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few mistakes:

- Your "`array`" contains the blank twice. This is the reason why `"F0 "` is not decode as expected. In fact, both `encode("70")` and `encode("7)")` with `rand=6` will yield the same result, which makes it *impossible* to reverse.
- The `if(value >= 0)` distinction is pointless given that your `value`s will always be positive for valid inputs
- Instead of doing `var a = this.array + this.array;` you should just use `% array.length` on the index
- Instead of switching on the type of the `value` in the `key` method, you should write two separate methods
- The `parseInt` in `decode` is pointless (if not even wrong) as the argument is an integer already

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer! A quick question, what would `% array.length` do? Secondly, is it just general development standards or is it incorrect syntax to switch on the type of `value` in the `key`?

Comment: [`%` is the remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) (also known as [*modulo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for positive inputs). Regarding the type switching, that's just a good development practice.

Comment: Alright cool. So you're saying instead of adding the array's together, I could just check for a value above `array.length` and set the value to that?

Comment: Yes, if you do `array[value % array.length]` you're guaranteed that the used index is always within the array (as long as `value` is positive); it will "wrap around" and start from the begin again if `value` is greater than the length.

Answer (score 0):

enjoy ))

```js
var fox = [ 8, 25, 43, 9, 85 ]; // this is key

function encoder( str, encode )
{
    var a = 0, out = '';
    for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        out += String.fromCharCode( str.charCodeAt(i) + ( encode ? fox[a] : -fox[a] ) );
        a = ( a + 1 ) % fox.length
    }
    return out
}

str1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim \
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi \
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor \
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt \
mollit anim id est laborum.';

str2 = 'TnÂ(|Êu9xÁwK|¾|9vº|EKlÄvlÉm {ui}y¾{|w¼(~rÉ49n¹(})\
ºqvÄl9nÂx)¾v|m¾l}u}Ku¶jnumKmÄtnuuzw¶(zrÆ}zY)ª|9w¾u9muurÂ(w¾i\
W)Æ})Ãw{Êl9ºz|}¶|wu}jÂkKu¶jrÈ(|¾()¶t~¾x9umzKlÄumÄ(|wÈm jÉ69o~¾\
{9~Ém9{Êz~KmÄt)¾v9nÅz~nÃl~rÉ()Ëw yÉi)Ëm}umnukuÊu9xÁw)º}9~¼qz)Ã}jux\
zr¶|7uMnÅ|~ {u{}uw|jºkz)¸}m¶|z)ÃwKyÇwnÃ|EK|ÊvKrÃ(| uÅi9~¾(o¾k)¹m{ÊvKvÄt}uivuq}KnÈ|9j·w v';

console.log( encoder(str1, true ))
console.log( encoder(str2, false ))
```